# backbone.js: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: backbone.js, instanceof

I'm newer with jquery and backbone, hope someone could help me with this error. I have a web application that, sometimes, throws this error in the console

> ```
> require.js:900 TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
>     at child.setElement (backbone.js?__nc__=1527837925799:1040)
>     at child._ensureElement (backbone.js?__nc__=1527837925799:1102)
>     at child.Backbone.View (backbone.js?__nc__=1527837925799:990)
>     at child [as constructor] (backbone.js?__nc__=1527837925799:1545)
>     at new child (backbone.js?__nc__=1527837925799:1545)
>     at child.initialize (application.js?__nc__=1527837925799:357)
>     at child.Inditex.Application (backbone-inditex-1.2.0.js?__nc__=1527837925799:27)
>     at new child (backbone.js?__nc__=1527837925799:1545)
>     at createApp (main.js:201)
> ```

```
at Object.execCb (require.js:1690)
```

If this error happens, with a reload of the webpage is fixed (sometimes with 3 or 4 times) but I can't know why this happens.

I have found the line where this error is thrown. In backbone.js file, the method setElement

> ```
> setElement: function(element, delegate) {
>       debugger;
>       if (this.$el) this.undelegateEvents();
>       this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
>       this.el = this.$el[0];
>       if (delegate !== false) this.delegateEvents();
>       return this;
>     },
> ```

sometimes, Backbone.$ is not an object and is when the error hapens.

¿Any idea for resolving this error? I'm using backbone.js 1.1.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you loading jQuery asynchronously? If jQuery is loaded after Backbone, `Backbone.$` might be undefined.

Comment: Hello GAntoine. Thanks for your response. I have checked how jQuery is loading and it's not loading asynchronously. These are the lines  <script src="${commonResourcesPath}/js/lib/jquery/1.9.0/jquery${resources.suffix}.js"></script>
 <script src="${commonResourcesPath}/js/lib/json2/1.0.0/json2${resources.suffix}.js"></script>
 <script src="${commonResourcesPath}/js/lib/bootstrap/2.3.1/bootstrap${resources.suffix}.js"></script>
 </script>
 <script src="${commonResourcesPath}/js/lib/backbone/1.1.0/backbone${resources.suffix}.js"></script>

Comment: First, dont jump directly to say it's a backbone error, this is probably a bad use in you code, can you check and post your **main.js** around the line **201**

Comment: Hi Ryad, thanks for your response. What are you looking for exactly? in my main.js, around the line 201, the code is this App.i18n_string = i18nModule;
        App.datatablei18n = datatableI18n;
        new Application({...});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, I could fix it change my main.js. The error was that, in some cases backbone was loaded before jquery were loaded. My main.js was like this

> shim       : {
>           'underscore'                        : {
>               exports: '_'
>           },
>           'backbone'                          : {
>               deps   : ['underscore'],
>               exports: 'Backbone'
>           }

I had to add a deps in backbone for jquery, like this

> shim       : {
>           'underscore'                        : {
>               exports: '_'
>           },
>           'backbone'                          : {
>               deps   : ['jquery','underscore'],
>               exports: 'Backbone'
>           }

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of this problem is backbone.js loaded before jQuery, so what you need to do is just make sure that jQuery loads before backbone.js.